# Xcode: Detecting when a navigation controller implemented "back button" is pressed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

**Scenario**

I have an app with a navigation controller. When the navigation controller pushes another controller onto the stack, in the upper left corner of the screen it shows the back button "<(title of the last view controller)".

**What I need**

I need something *like* (pseudo code)...

```
-(void)detectedBackButtonWasPushed {

    NSLog(@"Back Button Pressed");

    //Do what I need done

}
```

**Question**

Because this button is created *by the navigation controller* and I did not create this button in storyboards, **how do I get the back button 'hooked up' to a method like this?**

**examples of what Ive tried for Oleg**

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notification"];

    if (viewController == vc) {

        NSLog(@"BACK BUTTON PRESSED");
    }
}
```

Is this how I'm supposed to do it? Cause this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `viewWillDisappear` to detect this.

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) 
    { 
        [self backButtonPressed]; 
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 
    } 

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 
} 

-(void)backButtonPressed 
{ 
   NSLog(@"YEA"); 
}
```

Comment: Negative. You are right I can detect when the screen disappears. Problem is I have extra functionality (unhiding the tab bar at the bottom) that must happen **BEFORE** the screen disappears. Otherwise, the tab bar will continue to be hidden after the screen disappears. Which destroys my apps navigation. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: UINavigationControllerDelegate take a look at. And try to use - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: i will set up for you question

Comment: I've added code of what Ive tried and does not work.

Comment: are you using delegate correctly? without any warnings and so on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61437/discussion-between-oleg-gordiichuk-and-billy-a).

Comment: This doesn't work if the view controller you're dealing with is a child view controller, and as such isn't in the navigation stack directly.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I have solved this by setting the navigationBar leftItem to be a back button with a custom selector that dismisses the view along with whatever else it needed to do.

I might also suggest looking at the back button item and adding a target:self that is called on touch.